# How to do raster conditional comparisons in .NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, .net, raster-calculator

I am comparing a raster with a constant value by raster calculator. Now I want to do this in a c# code.

**Question**

Is there any process to do this kind of raster conditional comparison in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my answer. I thought it would be good if I answer the question.

[ILogicalOp Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILogicalOp_Interface/0040000000vz000000/) is the interface for raster comparison. This interface has all method for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to the [RasterConditionalOp CoClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/RasterConditionalOpClass_Class/004000000138000000/http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/RasterConditionalOpClass_Class/004000000138000000/)

> A mechanism for performing conditional operations on rasters.

You might want to bookmark the [ArcObjects SDK site](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html) for future reference :)

Comment: RasterConditionalOp Coclass has some thing like that. But there is no argument that takes whereClause or does some work based on query.

Comment: In python arcpy gives a lot support for raster operation. raster calculator, different spatial analyst methods can be called from python. Can those work done by .net?

Comment: Please read the docs. It's on the link on my answer.